# GeoServer can not find module in lib directory

Tags: geoserver, vector-tiles

I build GeoServer by myself,and build vectortiles module, copy jar file to web-inf/lib directory, but when I restart GeoServer, it don't find vectortiles. How I can find its reason?

Comment: Why are you building it yourself? did you assemble the whole zip file for the extension? what does the log file say?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 0):

The extensions are typically not self-contained, you need extra jars in addition to the module own jar file.

If you want to build yourself, get into the root of GeoServer and:

```
cd src
mvn clean install -Pvectortiles
cd web/app/target
```

The `geoserver.war` file produced in `web/app` now has the vector tiles plugin along with all necessary dependencies. Look into `web/app/pom.xml` for more profile names, in case you'd like to include other extensions.